# REG Query to find a specify value of registry and if it exist than go to

Tags: file, batch-file

I want to find a specify value of registry and if it exist than go to execute the job

Here my script used but not successful

```
:SkinReplacementKIS64
CLS
ECHO.
REG Query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\KasperskyLab\AVP19.0.0\settings" /v "EnableSelfProtection" |find "1" >nul & IF %ErrorLevel% EQU 0 (
ECHO.
ECHO Please disable Kaspersky self-defense first before doing the action!
ECHO.
pause
GOTO SkinReplacementKIS64
) else (
CLS
ECHO ***************************************************************************************
ECHO Kaspersky Tweaker v1.4 for KFA, KAV, KIS, KTS, KSC (19.0.0.1088)
ECHO ***************************************************************************************
ECHO.
net stop AVP19.0.0
dark_skin_kis.exe /p12345678
net start AVP19.0.0
ECHO.
pause
GOTO KIS64
)
```

what am I wrong ? Please help

Comment: Your issue may be that the output of `Reg Query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\KasperskyLab\AVP19.0.0\settings" /V "EnableSelfProtection"` contains the registry key itself which would match the string `1` in `AVP19.0.0`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `for /f`to get the value an test it?

```
@echo off

:SkinReplacementKIS64
CLS
ECHO.
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('REG Query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\KasperskyLab\AVP19.0.0\settings" /v "EnableSelfProtection"') do set "$val=%%a"

if %$val%==1 (
ECHO.
ECHO Please disable Kaspersky self-defense first before doing the action!
ECHO.
pause
GOTO SkinReplacementKIS64
) else (
CLS
ECHO ***************************************************************************************
ECHO Kaspersky Tweaker v1.4 for KFA, KAV, KIS, KTS, KSC (19.0.0.1088)
ECHO ***************************************************************************************
ECHO.
net stop AVP19.0.0
dark_skin_kis.exe /p12345678
net start AVP19.0.0
ECHO.
pause
GOTO KIS64
)
```

Comment: Please see pictures and help: EnableSelfProtection = 0 but can't execute the job https://imgur.com/Ar9gi78 https://imgur.com/DhEwFeW https://imgur.com/PjFhzuC

Comment: Check my Edit ! You have to get the value in a `VAR` with `FOR/F` to test it !

Comment: still not work, it appear an error and and quickly shut off

Answer (score 0):

Based on my comment, the easiest way would be to exclude the first line from your potential match:

```bat
Reg Query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\KasperskyLab\AVP19.0.0\settings" /V "EnableSelfProtection" 2>Nul | Find /V "HKLM" | Find "1" >Nul ...
```

*You may even wish to use `x1` instead of `1` to provide more certainty too.*